# node.js Telnet Client testing using Hercules Terminal

Tags: node.js, tcp, client, telnet

I am using the npm telnet client

I would like to test it first using a terminal using `Hercules.exe`. However, I always just get "connection time out".

I have set the Hercules Terminal with a TCP Server to Port 23 and it is running on a local machine with IP  192.169.1.79. However when I try to Telnet to the Hercules terminal, all I get is "socket time out" . Any clues would be appreciated.

```
var Telnet = require('telnet-client')
var connection = new Telnet()

var params = {
  host: '192.168.1.79',
  port: 23,
  shellPrompt: '/ # ',
  timeout: 1500,
  // removeEcho: 4
}

connection.on('ready', function(prompt) {
  connection.exec(cmd, function(err, response) {
    console.log(response)
  })
})

connection.on('timeout', function() {
  console.log('socket timeout!')
  connection.end()
})

connection.on('close', function() {
  console.log('connection closed')
})

connection.connect(params)
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. 
1. In Hecules TCP Server . You need to send back the shell prompt '/ # ' within the Timeout time frame

2. Also you can set the cmd = 'testing' or whatever you want to send and you can see it in the Hercules Received Data window.